# Indentation Error: Vim creates invisible indents

Tags: python, vim, indentation

As you may be able to see (from the screenshot below) there is an additional level of indentation that I did not make and there are no tabs or spaces corresponding to it. Retyping the code does not fix this. The original file was cloned from github. I am using gVim 7+ on Ubuntu 12.04 and to the best of my knowledge the original file was also written on a Linux machine.

Here's the screenshot:

[image: VIM Screenshot]

I believe I have indented my code correctly but the indentation guides are showing a new indentation level and Python emits indentation errors.

I am not very clear with line endings and encodings.

Comment: Is the original file indented by tabs or with spaces? Depending on that, you have to adjust the "expandtab" setting - see `:help expandtab`. (p.s. [syntax for including images in markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img))

Comment: Thanks everyone ,the problem was with tabs and spaces .Adding this to my vimrc
    
    set shiftwidth=4
    set tabstop=4
    set expandtab
and running

    :%retab 

fixed the problem,Vim automatically fixes all indentation space and tab mix ups.

Comment: @vstm i dont have enough so reputation for that!

Answer (score 2):

I cloned [`https://github.com/flazzarini/conkyconfig/blob/master/tools/anowplaying.py`](https://github.com/flazzarini/conkyconfig/blob/master/tools/anowplaying.py) from `git://github.com/flazzarini/conkyconfig.git` and viewed the file in Vim with...

```
:set listchars=tab:>-,trail:-,eol:$ list
```

...to highlight tabs, spaces and other whitespace differently.

The original author used tabs for indentation. I suspect you are using using spaces but cannot tell from your screenshot.

Invoking Python with the following option...

```
-tt  -- issue errors about inconsistent tab usage
```

...will help you keep your indentation consistent.

You should probably `set noexpandtab tabstop=8 shiftwidth=8` (perhaps in a [**`modeline`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6)) to be consistent with the original source. That way, should you ever submit a patch, only the lines you've really added or updated will be submitted.